# How do I move this icon/button? CSS?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm just learning asp.net, VB, SQL and CSS. I am writing a dating site and want the "likes" icon to sit next to the other 3 centralised icons just above it. The first 3 icons are simply images at the moment but the Likes icon is in DIVS and does function correctly but ends up on the row below even though there's plenty of space to fit it next to them. Many thanks for any help...

```
<asp:Image ID="Imagelove" runat="server" width="90px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/loveicon.png" />
<asp:Image ID="ImageGift" width="90px" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/files/images/gift.png" />
<asp:Image ID="ImageReport" width="90px" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/files/images/report.png" />

<div style="width:90px; height:89px; position:relative; background: url('/files/images/likebutton.png'); cursor: pointer;" onClick="addLike('<%# Eval("orderID")%>')">
    <div style="font-size:12px; color:#000; background:#ffffff; border:1px solid #000; padding:0 3px; float:left; margin: 0px 0 0 55px;" id="<%# Eval("orderID")%>"><%# Eval("likeCounter")%>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: PS. I didn't really want to use "Float" as I want the icons to kinda move freely depending on screen size.

Comment: Have you ever heard about [`float`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)? Also, please create a working [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) (For this you need to put the **output** html in the snippet, For example, replace the asp tag `<asp:Image` with the `<img` tag you see in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself thank you. I added display: inline-block; in to the DIV Style="" part.